# Quickly add Scrolling to Window

Tags: application-development, gtk, pygtk, glade, overlay-scrollbars

while creating my ubuntu application, I wanted to add in several images and then allow the user to scroll through them. The problem I am having, is that it just cuts the image off, and there are no overlay scrollbars. I even have the `scrolledwindow` function in there. I could manually link separate pages to the articles, but I would like it to be all on one page to save room. I was greatly appreciate any help regarding this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I'm not sure if this'll work for you as well, but I was able to fix it, by adding a GtkScrolledWindow with a GtkViewport that has a GtkBox within it. Sorta like this:

[image: Image of object stack within glade]

I hope that fixes the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks man :D. I tried doing something similar, but I never thought of adding a box within the viewport :o!